# Elasticsearch filtering with input array where

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Our requirement is to filter objects by an array field of data by giving an input array to elasticsearch. Any combination input array elements is match with **mentions** array.

#### Small example

```
data:[
  {"name": "xxxx", "mentions": ["X", "Y"]},
  {"name": "yyyy", "mentions": ["K", "L", "M"]},
  {"name": "zzz", "mentions": ["X", "L"]},
]  
Input: [X, Y, K, L]
Output:[
  {"name": "xxxx", "mentions": ["X", "Y"]},
  {"name": "zzz", "mentions": ["X", "L"]}
]
```

Objects must be filtered according to **mentions** field, where each member of mentions array must be in the given input array, if there is any inconsistency, then ignore the object.
**Terms** query or bool with must field is not solving our problem.

Comment: Could you share your mapping? Also it would be great if you can share the queries you have tried. From what I understand, you want all the documents which are having `X Y K L` in the mentions field, correct?

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal 'X Y K L' having all of them is not mandatory but, any combination of X Y K L is ok in mentions array such as X Y or X L, as it is seen in the output. The mapping is the same as with data array.

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic solution is to make use of a [Regex Expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) in a [Regex Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html):

Below is how your query would be:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [                    <---- Note this.
        {
          "regexp": {
            "mentions": "[^XYKL]"      <---- Note this. 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Square Brackets `[...]` would mean to match one of the characters present.

What I've done is simply used a `Negate Character ^` inside the bracket and wrapped that Regex Logic inside a `must_not` clause of a  [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and it should give you what you are looking for.

The query would only return documents with values `X Y K L` values. Any other values barring that, it would not return those documents.

Note that I'm assuming the field `mentions` is of type `keyword`.

Comment: **mentions** is not keyword it is an array of keywords

Comment: Yes, the above should work. If not please share me your mapping. I've tested it on array only.